# Laravel policy not being invoked at all

Tags: laravel, eloquent, acl, policy

I set up a class for deleting comments left by users under an item model in a web page:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Comment;
use App\Model_comment;
use App\User;
use App\Post;


class CommentPolicy
{


    /**
     *
     * Defines if User can delete a Comment
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @param Comment $comment
     * @param Post $post
     * @return bool
     */
    public function deleteComment(User $user, Comment $comment, Post $post)
    {

        return ($user->id === $comment->user_id || $user->id === $post->user_id);

    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     * @param Model_comment $model_comment
     * @return bool
     */
    public function deleteModelComment(User $user, Model_comment $model_comment)
    {

        return ($user->id === $model_comment->user_id);

    }

}
```

Now I am trying to use this to show a button for deleting the comment.
While the "deleteComment" for posts comments is working the "deleteModelComment" is not passing at all, not any errors given.
The class is registered correctly under Auth Service Provider.
I am invoking it in the blade view like this:

```
@can('deleteModelComment', $c)
     <button id="deletecmnt_{{$c->id}}" class="fa fa-minus pull-right"
             aria-hidden="true"
             data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}"></button>
@endcan
```

$c is the Model_comment. Any clue?

Comment: What is **Model_comment**, your `deleteModelComment` method is waiting for that one. Not **Comment**

Comment: yes I know, $c is Model_comment. I double checked by `dd($c)` -> `Model_comment {#312 ▼ bla bla }`

Comment: And you have added this in `AuthServiceProvider` too?

Comment: yes -> `Comment::class => CommentPolicy::class,`

Comment: I have no idea what can it be, but try to return false. and check if anything changes.

Comment: Solved, I made a new class Model_commentPolicy.php, moved the logic there and registered it in Auth Service Provider `Model_comment::class => Model_commentPolicy::class,` but now that I think I can leave it in CommentPolicy and register the `Model_comment::class => CommentPolicy::class` --- edit, yes it works like that too.